# grep with regex containing pipe character

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, grep

I am trying to grep with regex that contains pipe character `|`. However, It doesn't work as expected. The regex does not match the `|` inclusively as seen in the attach image below.

[image]

this is my bash command

`cat data | grep "{{flag\|[a-z|A-Z\s]+}}"`

the sample data are the following

```
| 155||NA||{{flag|Central African Republic}}||2.693||NA||0.000||0.000||0.019||0.271||0.281||0.057||2.066
|{{flagicon|Kosovo}} ''[[Kosovo]]'' <ref name="KOS" group=Note>{{Kosovo-note}}</ref>
|{{flagicon|Somaliland}} [[Somaliland|Somaliland region]]
|{{flagicon|Palestine}} ''[[Palestinian Territories]]''{{refn|See the following on statehood criteria:
```

the expected output is

```
| 155||NA||{{flag|Central African Republic}}||2.693||NA||0.000||0.000||0.019||0.271||0.281||0.057||2.066
```

However, having tested it with [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rhIqLF/1), the result came out as expected.

Comment: POSIX (Grep, e.g.), Vim, and Perl are the three major syntaxes for regexes you'll encounter; unfortunately, each of them is quite different, in both ability and syntax. Luckilly, almost all modern software has settled on Perl's syntax. That's the reason any online service will disagree somewhat with grep: JavaScript's regex engine is based on Perl syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that `grep` accepts `\|` as a separator between alternative search expressions (like `|` in `egrep`, where `\|` matches a literal `|`).

Apart from that, your expression has other problems:-

- `+` is supported in `egrep` (or `grep -E`) only.
- `\s` is not supported within a `[]` character group.
- I don't see the need for `|` in the character group.

So the following works for `grep`:-

```
grep "{{flag|[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]*}}" <temp
```

Or (thanks to [Glenn Jackman](https://superuser.com/users/4714/glenn-jackman)'s input):-

```
grep "{{flag|[a-zA-Z ]\+}}" <temp
```

In `egrep` the `{}` characters have special significance, so they need to be escaped:-

```
egrep "\{\{flag\|[a-zA-Z ]+\}\}" <temp
```

Note that I have removed the unnecessary use of `cat`.

Comment: You can also do `<temp egrep ...`, to put temp back at the beginning where it feels natural

Comment: @jpaugh - Yes, I know, but I usually avoid it because it doesn't work with internal commands.

Comment: Really? I started using it to break myself of the `cat` habit; I always think of the file first. Looking at `help` in bash, I can't see many built-ins which use  stdio. It does break `read`, though; sure enough.

Comment: with basic grep regex, you can change `[a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]*` to `[a-zA-Z ]\+` -- ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html#grep-regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @glennjackman - Thanks very much: I didn't know about that, and I shall certainly use it from now on. I wonder how many of the other ERE specifics can be escaped in BRE...

Comment: @jpaugh - I not infrequently use things like `while read -r l; do ...; done` to handle lines of input, and this works fine with redirection at the end, but not at the beginning. It is annoying, and almost qualifies as a bug, but I have learned to live with it. Otherwise, I'd use your format as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your request is extract the line contains `flag|`, using `grep` may is too complex.

Here I use `sed` and `awk` to extrect it, command is

```
sed -r -n '/flag\|/p' /tmp/temp

awk 'match($0,/flag\|/){print}' /tmp/temp
```

Comment: This does not use the same search criteria as the questioner wants: it can yield more lines than are required. If you simplify the search to this extent, then the `grep` string is equally simplified.